# c++ std::map runs out_of_range

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am solving SPOJ problem [FLIB](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FLIB/) and I have tried implementing this using Maps like this -

```
long long FiboSum(long long n) {
    if(n==1||n==0) return n;
    if(fiboDict.count(n)) return (long long) fiboDict.at(n);
    if(n%2==0) { 
        //calculate term -- value to that key
        fiboDict.insert(pair<long,long>(n,term));
    }
    else { 
        //calculate term
        fiboDict.insert(pair<long,long>(n,term));
    }
    return (long long) fiboDict.at(n);
}
```

`fiboDict` is the map, but the problem needs me to calculate for `( 0 <= n < 2^51)` but KEY value can't hold such high values, and I am getting Error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what():  
map::at
```

How could I make it hold large values? or If there is alternative then please suggest.

Comment: Why do you use `long long` in the code, but not for the key?

Comment: Oh my God, how silly..I am sorry if have wasted your time, I think its the insomnia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you make map of :

```
pair<long long,long long>
```

then?